# Can not find the error in Sales entry model form

Tags: oracle-apex

When I deduct the down payment from the price on my sales entry model form, the Rest _Amount and Paid_Amount paid are accurately displayed. However, the Down Payment and Paid Amount value amounts are not stored in the database. On the Down Payment item, I built two dynamic actions for this occurrence.

Create Two Dynamic Actions

**A.** Click the Dynamic Actions tab. Right-click the Change node and select Create Dynamic Action.

Click the New node and set the following properties

Property:-         Name

Name:-             Set down payment

Selection Type:-       Items

Item:-             P13_ DOWN_PAYMENT

Click the Show node to set the following properties

Property:-       Value

Action:-             Set Value

Set Type:-      PL/SQL Function Body

PL/SQL Function:-   RETURN :P13_PRICE-TO_NUMBER(:P13_DOWN_PAYMENT);

Click the Show node to set the following properties

Property:-  Value

Action:-    Set Value

Set Type:-  PL/SQL Function Body

PL/SQL Function RETURN:- :P13_DOWN_PAYMENT;

Items to Submit:-   P13_DOWN_PAYMENT

Selection Type (Affected Elements):-    Items

Item:   P13_PAID_AMOUNT

**B**. Click the Dynamic Actions tab. Right-click the Change node and select Create Dynamic
Action.

Click the New node and set the following properties.

Property:-        Name

Name:-           Set paid amount

Selection Type:-     Items

Item:-           P13_DOWN_PAYMENT

Click the Show node to set the following properties

Property:-                            Value

Action:-                                  Set Value

Set Type:-                            PL/SQL Function Body

PL/SQL Function:-                        RETURN :P13_DOWN_PAYMENT;

Items to Submit:-                        P13_DOWN_PAYMENT

Selection Type (Affected Elements):-      Items

Item:-                              P13_PAID_AMOUNT

Comment: With this information it's kind of hard to answer. You're assuming that the dynamic action is the reason for the changed item not being saved to the database but I doubt that. Have you tried running the page in debug and checking what the value is ? What is the item type of those 2 page items ? It probably makes sense to create a similar test case on the emp table on apex.oracle.com in a new workspace and share the credentials here so someone can have a proper look at the issue.

Comment: If the page items is NOT a text field, try changing one of them to text field just for debugging and check if it works ok then.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Koen! Actually, I'm new to Oracle apex and trying to follow a tutorial..don't know the exact debugging system.. can you suggest me a tutorial on that?

Comment: Google "how to debug an apex application" ?

Comment: After debugging
select SALES_ID,       SALES_DATE,       CUSTOMER_ID,       CUSTOMER_NAME,       CUSTOMER_PHONE,       PRODUCT_ID,       PROD_NAME,       PRICE,       DOWN_PAYMENT,       NUMBER_OF_INSTALL,       REST_AMOUNT,       PAID_AMOUNT             from TEST_SALESwhere SALES_ID = :P12_SALES_ID